# Stencil Image low resolution

Tags: texturing, texture-painting

I am trying to texture paint a mesh using a pretty high resolution stencil image..

But when I try to zoom into the image to paint the details...it appears as if it was very low res...
Is there any way to make it appear highres in the viewport??

Comment: Can you add a screen shot.? What's the resolution of the painted texture?

Comment: choose any image higher than 2k...it appears blurry..

Comment: Can you show us a printscreen of your UV map and tell us what is the resolution of the texture you paint on?

Comment: it paints perfectly on the mesh, its just the stencil overlay preview that is low res.

Comment: I haven't found a setting yet that changes this - I am hoping that with the 2.8 viewport project that this kind of thing will be answered.

Comment: The resolution of the painted texture depends also on the resolution of your image texture (the one you paint on) not only on the stencil image so of course it's going to be pixelated when you zoom in too close.

Answer (score 0):

Try <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> and then move your mouse to zoom in to the image.

Answer (score -1):

On the right side of the screen there should be a tab for *Viewport Display* properties. Go to *Viewport Settings* and change them however you need them.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).